# Passing arguments to factory

Tags: angularjs

I am building an app using AngularJs.

I have a function (createStarMarkup) that returns a bunch of HTML based on a number.

```
function(rating) {
  var rating = Number(rating);

  var markup = "";

  //Do some stuff

  return markup;
}
```

I would like to be able to use this function multiple places in my application, so I defined it as a service in a Utility module.

```
var app = angular.module('utilities', []);

app.factory('createStarMarkup', function(rating) {
  var rating = Number(rating);

  var markup = "";

  // Do some stuff

  return markup;
});
```

I then add the 'utilities' module as a dependency to one of my other modules, and inject the service into the controller.

```
var app = angular.module('reviews', ['ionic', 'utilities']);

app.controller('reviewController',
  ['$scope', '$ionicActionSheet', 'createStarMarkup', function($scope, $ionicActionSheet, createStarMarkup){...});
```

This produces the following error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ratingProvider <- $rating <- createStarMarkup
```

The error goes away if I remove the rating parameter in the createStarMarkup function. Am I on the right track with using factory or should I look into something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your factory definition is not valid. please change it as follows

```
app.factory('createStartupServices', ['',  function() {
    return {
      getMarkup: function(rating) {
        var rating = Number(rating);

        var markup = "";

         // Do some stuff

          return markup;
      },
    }
  }
]);
```

And your controller, you need to get the method `getMarkup` as follows

```
var app = angular.module('reviews', ['ionic', 'utilities']);

app.controller('reviewController',['$scope', '$ionicActionSheet', 'createStartupServices', function($scope, $ionicActionSheet, createStartupServices){
    //createStartupServices.getMarkup(123);
});
```

Comment: you are welcome. please mark this as a answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
app.factory('createStarMarkup', function(rating) {
```

You are trying to inject a service called `rating`, that doesn't exist.

What are you trying to to is this:

```
app.factory('createStarMarkup', function() {
 Service = {};
 Service.myFunction = function(rating) {
  var rating = Number(rating);

  var markup = "";

  // Do some stuff

  return markup;
  }
return Service;
});
```

In this way you can inject the createStarMarkup in any controller/directive/service and use the function like:

```
createStarMarkup.myFunction(rating);
```