# function undefined in angularjs factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have declared a factory with three functions in it.  I was able to call get function but not the other two.

```
 todomvc.factory('todoStorage', function ($q,$http) {
        var STORAGE_ID = 'todos-angularjs-perf';
     function get(){
       return $http.get('test.json');
     }
    function display(){
        console.log("testing");
    }
     function put(todos) {
        console.log(todos);
       return $http.get('test.json');
     }
     return{get:get};
     return{put:put};
    });
```

Calling the functions in controller,

```
display(); // undefined here
todoStorage.put(todos); // undefined here too
```

Where I am doing a mistake?

Comment: your factory defination is wrong..check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906503/passing-arguments-to-factory/26906603#26906603

Answer (score 2):

A factory in angular is a function that returns an object.

You have multiple return statements:

```
return {get: get};
return {pug: put};
```

Change them to:

```
return {
  get: get,
  put: put,
  display: display
}
```